# How to count items inside multi-dimension collections in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to count items inside multi-dimension laravel collections

This my query

```
 $weeklySmsReport = Record::whereNotNull('created_at')->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()])
        ->orderBy('created_at')
        ->get()
         ->groupBy([function ($group) {
            return Carbon::parse($group->created_at)->format('l');
        },'status']);
```

This is the result

[image]

I want to return multi-dimensions collection like this

```
  [ "Monday" => [
              "failed"=>1 (total count of failed items),
              "Processed" => 2 (total count of processed items)
              ]
```

]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a nested map:

```
$weeklySmsReport = $weeklySmsReport->map(function ($day) {
  return $day->map(function($status) {
    return $status->count();
  });
});
```